# How to define cluster centers in Weka K-Means cluster?

Tags: cluster-computing, weka, k-means

I can specify initial cluster centers in SPSS K-Means cluster by importing an external file. Is there any similar function in Weka that I can specify initial cluster centers explicitly instead of generating them by random numbers ? I can't find any options about this......